# Trouble setting up yii cron job

Tags: php, yii, cron, yii-extensions

I'm trying to test a cron job locally on a XAMPP environment. I've been following the information given here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-crontab/

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26551-setting-up-cronjob/

I have a command written that works when I call it manually, i have the crontab extension extracted in the extensions folder, I'm importing it in config/main.php like so,

```
'application.extensions.crontab.*',
```

I wrote a my_crontabs file with this line,

```
* * * * * user php /path/to/console.php test run
```

but it doesn't seem to work, i don't know why, none of my peers are adept at yii enough to help me. So that's where i am. Any insight is appreciated. If you need more detail or code, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your command by typing the following line in your crontab editor:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/app/protected/yiic.php yourcommandname argument1 argument2 ...
```

Good luck!